# Suma de campos en SQL

Tags: sql

tengo dos tablas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que intento hacer es sacar la deuda de esas dos tablas, espero sus comentarios, gracias por su tiempo

Comment: intentaste algo?

Comment: para que puedas esperar ayuda no es solo mostrar tus tablas que parecen mas una hoja de excel, además explica que llevas hecho y cual gestor de bases de datos sql usas?

Comment: Cual seria la deuda? como se calcularia? como se relacionan las tablas?

Comment: Es un nuevo usuario, no entiendo el afán de votar negativo, eso repercute en que ya no pueda preguntar más y hacerse otra cuenta y sobresaturar SO. Se le explica cómo funciona la comunidad, no sean tan banales.

Comment: pues es una hoja de excel, es una descripción de lo que que ya tengo, no creo que tenga importancia como llegue a esa datos finales, lo que espero es como podria calcular esa deuda en sqlserver

Comment: los votos negativos no son permanentes @AlbertoSiurob si el OP atiende a las observaciones hechas, dicha votación se puede volver ahora positiva, tampoco seas tan drástico en que le hacemos un mal por que no es así

Comment: Por que ya lo pasé @element cuando era nuevo en preguntar e iniciaba aquí las preguntas que hacías no tenían el estandar épico como el que pregunta con 20K de reputación, y terminó SO por evitar que siguiera yo preguntando hasta que arreglara mis preguntas, las arreglé pero nadie se tomó la molestia en votar positivo después, tuve que crearme una nueva cuenta, te apuesto que en cuanto el OP arregle su pregunta no te inmutarás en quitarle el negativo. Saludos.

Comment: no asegures lo que no te consta @AlbertoSiurob saludos, aquí la intención es ayudar así que no generalices por que te paso a ti le va a pasar a todos

Comment: che pregunte algo, el que no le interese ayudar omita lo visto

Comment: De lo que puedo entender de las tablas, tienes una tabla de deudas y otra de cobros realizados. Deseas calcular la deuda total, restando a la deuda de la tabla 1 el cobro de la tabla 2. Ahora, si eso no es lo que deseas hacer, entonces debes explicarte mejor. Si puedes poner el código que tengas en vez de una imágen eso sería preferible. Así podríamos ayudarte. Igual necesitamos saber cómo obtienes los datos, el motor de SQL que usas, desde dónde lo usas y además al menos la relación de las tablas. Aunque se vea en la imagen que tabla2 está relacionada con tabla1, necesitamos que especifiques.

Comment: No incluyó código pero al menos quedaron bonitos los colores.

Comment: De lo que puedo entender de las tablas, tienes una tabla de deudas y otra de cobros realizados. Deseas calcular la deuda total, restando a la deuda de la tabla 1 el cobro de la tabla 2, exactamente, el motor es sqlserver

Answer (score -1, accepted):

creo que si te falto formular mas la pregunta, decir tu motor de db desde la misma pregunta.... Pero bueno, viendo tus comentarios espero poderte ayudar y sobre todo haberte entendido.

```
-- VOY A SUPONER TUS TABLAS DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA
DECLARE @tablaDeudas TABLE(cod INT, importe MONEY);
DECLARE @tablaCobros TABLE(cod INT, codDeuda INT, importe MONEY);

SELECT t1.cod AS codigoDeuda, SUM(t1.importe) AS deudaOriginal, 
    COUNT(t2.cod) AS cantidadCobros, SUM(ISNULL(t2.importe,0)) AS cobrosImporte, 
    SUM(t1.importe - ISNULL(t2.importe,0)) AS deudaActual 
FROM @tablaDeudas t1
    LEFT JOIN @tablaCobros t2 ON t2.codDeuda = t1.cod
```

Espero te sirva! Saludos!

Comment: La idea es ayudar a quien haya mostrado un avance en la solución, no hacerle el trabajo completo. Por favor lee un poco sobre como funciona este sitio.

Comment: Tienes razon Shaz, como ya leiste en la otra pregunta, solo trato de obtener reputacion para poder usar el sitio en todo su esplendor, pero bueno. Repito tienes completamente la razon!!, estamos generando una comunidad un poco vale madre, que quieren que se les haga el trabajo, no entiendo este tipo de gente ya que hay miles de articulos/cursos/videos enseñando cosas asi de basicas.

Comment: Te agradezco que dejes de responder preguntas incompletas o te reportaré a los moderadores. Si quieres ganar reputación, puedes: 1. Responder preguntas bien formuladas, 2. Hacer ediciones (aunque veo que tu ortogafía y tu gramática no son tan buenas), 3. Formular preguntas.

Comment: Enterado y gracias por el voto negativo =). Tambien gracias por lo de la ortografia (sin acento). Tendre en cuenta las preguntas para cuando tenga alguna duda. Saludos